# How do I import a monthly Excel file into an Access table using a button of a form?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Excel file that I would like to import into an Access table. The whole things sounds overly simple yet I can't figure it out.

I know I can manually do it by using the import ribbon in Access but would rather use a click of a button off of the main form.

```
  Private Sub Import_Monthly_Data_Click()

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport

tablename:="All Returns", filename:=C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Keith Gonshorek\Top 100 -May.xlsx,

HasFieldNames:=True

Exit_Import_Monthly_Data_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or, what isn't working correctly?

Comment: Compile error:  User-defined type not defined

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Access library in VBE? I get the same error and it points to `acImport` which is not native to Excel VBA.

Comment: Do you have an example of a simple import from scratch?

Comment: No, I haven't used Access in a long time. I don't like it, so I use SQL Server instead. Did you add the reference to the Microsoft Access library? That is almost certainly one of your issues.

Comment: @Kyle I've revised my code to try something that seems a little more simple yet I still end up with a compile error and it points to the tablename:= line stating it's a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it manually using the import process you described, you should have the option to save that import process. Then you can tie this code to the button on the form.

```
docmd.RunSavedImportExport("SavedImportExportName")
```

[Here is a little more about the docmd.runsavedimportexport method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834375.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to export from Excel to Access.

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacexportado

To import into Access from Excel, try one of the concepts mentioned at the URL below.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm